# CSS Mobile Navigation Changes for Portrait and Landscape

Tags: css, class, mobile, orientation

I have a series of pages on my site that contain ".iframe1".  The .iframe1 needs to be viewable in both portrait and landscape modes on mobile phones, but I needed to tweak 2 things to make it function properly.

1.) Landscape Mode: Block "#main-header" from appearing altogether.

2.) Portrait Mode: Pad the top of my content area. (#main-header covers the top of my content while in portrait.)

I have completed #1, but can't seem to figure out how to achieve #2. I have combined them into one task because I feel that there is a chance they'll conflict if written separately.

Both of the following entries acheive #1 but not #2:

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 480px ) and ( max-width: 768px ) {
#main-header {
display: none !important;
}
.iframe1 {
padding-top: 30px !important;
}
}
```

---

```
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) and (max-width: 768px) {
#main-header {
display: none !important;
}
.iframe1 {
padding-top: 30px !important;
}
}
```

Anyone have ideas about how I can get #2 to work?

Thanks in advance,

KV

Comment: In #2 you are using `(orientation:landscape)` didn't you say you'd like this when it is oriented in portrait mode? Change landscape to portrait

Comment: Ahh that's stupid of me. You're right, sorry I'm still getting started with CSS.  The problem is, if I insert (orientation:portrait)  on the first line, #main-header will be eliminated from portrait mode. I'm trying to avoid this.

So to summarize- 
For portrait mode I want to preserve #main-header, and to add  padding-top  to .iframe1. 
For landscape, I want to remove #main-header...


All comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I ended up achieving the desired effect by eliminating the `orientation:` attribute, and simply by using `min-width` and `max-width`:

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 481px ) and ( max-width: 768px ) {
#main-header {
display: none !important;
}
.iframe1 {
padding-top: 30px !important;
}
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 480px ) {
.iframe1 {
padding-top: 119px !important;
}
}
```

This way I was able to eliminate `#main-header` entirely from landscape orientations, and to keep it in portrait mode with the proper `padding-top`.

KV